# require('net').connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want use node 'net' module in Vue.js.
Also I'm executing following commands :

`npm i --save net`

`node : v10.16.0 //`

`vue : 3.9.1 //`

`project : make vue-cli //`

**javascript**

```
const net_client = require('net');
export default {
  mounted() {
    client = net_client.connect(9909, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    })

    client.on('data', function(data)) {
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
}
```

**Error**

`TypeError: net_client.connect is not a function.`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Net` is `node.js` (SSR) package and isn't available on the browser since the browser cannot open arbitrary TCP sockets.

Comment: host socket server is socket-server in python.   Question1) so... what module i can use(I'm client) in browser?   Question2) change host server module to socket.io(python) ?